# Find most recent (non-future) date from a list of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot, lateral-join

Assume a table like this (in actuality I have 50 date columns to compare):

| ID | MY_DATE_1 | MY_DATE_2 | MY_DATE 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-1 | 2022-11-1 | 2022-12-1 |
| 2 | 2022-10-31 | 2022-11-31 | 2022-12-31 |

For each record, I want to get the **most recent, non-blank past date** (less than today's date) looking across all date columns.

So I would want these results (given a current date of 2022-11-15):

| ID | LATEST_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-1 |
| 2 | 2022-10-31 |

I found this code elsewhere, but it just gets the max date across columns, and I need to add the condition somewhere for "max past" and not just "max overall" but I'm not experienced with `CROSS APPLY` and don't know if I can modify this query or if there's another way to write it that will work.

```
SELECT MA.MaxDate
FROM <my_table> AS MT
CROSS APPLY (
 SELECT MAX(VA.LDate)
 FROM (VALUES(MT.MY_DATE_1),(MT.MY_DATE_2),(MT.MY_date_3)) VA(LDate)
) AS MA(MaxDate)
```

Comment: Just add a `where LDATE < getdate()` in the cross apply.

Comment: I was confused on the syntax of `VA(LDATE)` hence wasn't sure what to put in a WHERE clause. What is LDATE?

Comment: LDATE is the column alias name; Having 50 date columns is your root problem, if these were *rows* you wouldn't need any pivoting of columns into rows at all.

Comment: Assuming a typo, but I see 11/31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter before aggregation. Here is one way to do it:

```
select mt.id, max(va.ldate) as maxdate
from my_table as mt
cross apply ( values (mt.my_date_1), (mt.my_date_2), (mt.my_date_3) ) va(ldate)
where va.ldate > getdate()
group by mt.id
```

Comment: Less than `getdate()` I guess, but I'll try. Any clue whether CROSS APPLY would be better/worse than UNPIVOT (a keyword I only just learned today)?

Comment: I would suggest ignoring the pivot/unpivot syntax, it's syntactic sugar that's quite restrictive and, imho, not particularly intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want list all 50 date columns, you can use a bit of JSON to dynamically UNPIVOT your data without actually using Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply  (
                 Select Value = max(Value)
                  From  OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  ) 
                  Where [Key] not in ('ID','OtherColumns','ToExclude')
                    and try_convert(date,value)<=getdate()
              ) B
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Could you do `WHERE [Key] Like ...` instead? I have about 200 columns in the table, so listing 50 to check is better than listing 150 to exclude.

Comment: @redOctober13 Absolutely.    That said, 200 columns is a bit much... performance wise you may be better off enumerating the columns is the CROSS APPLY as GMB suggests.   But try it.  The performance may surprise you

Comment: It did seem to run quite a bit slower. I used `Where Left([Key],7) = 'G_DATE_`

Comment: @redOctober13 I would have gone with  WHERE [Key] like 'G_DATE%' but I would expect a performance hit considering 150 extra columns are being processed